# Is it possible to cross-compile C++ source code, that was originally written for Microsoft's Windows to Gnu/linux?

Tags: windows, compiling, source

I am trying to compile software that was meant for windows from source. The software I am specifically trying to compile is an application called Keeperfx for Dungeon Keeper. I enjoy that game so I thought I could compile its source on linux and see if it works. However, I am not having so much luck.

Doing the `make` command only gives this output:

```
mkdir -p obj/std
Building file: src/main.cpp
g++ -I"directx/include" -I"sdl/include" -I"libav/include" -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -MMD -MP -MF"obj/std/main.d" -MT"obj/std/main.d" -march=i686 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3   -DBFDEBUG_LEVEL=0  -o"obj/std/main.o" "src/main.cpp"
src/main.cpp:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
 #pragma region includes
 ^
src/main.cpp:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
Makefile:658: recipe for target 'obj/std/main.o' failed
make: *** [obj/std/main.o] Error 1
```

So I thought I would use mingw. But I keep getting errors.

```
../src/bflib_crash.c: In function ‘sigstr’:
../src/bflib_crash.c:77:10: error: ‘SIGBREAK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     case SIGBREAK : return "Ctrl-Break (Win32)";
          ^
../src/bflib_crash.c:77:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../src/bflib_crash.c: In function ‘LbErrorParachuteInstall’:
../src/bflib_crash.c:189:12: error: ‘SIGBREAK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     signal(SIGBREAK,ctrl_handler);
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:26:0:
/usr/include/fcntl.h:202:12: error: conflicting types for ‘creat’
 extern int creat (const char *__file, mode_t __mode) __nonnull ((1));
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:25:0:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:314:15: note: previous declaration of ‘creat’ was here
   int __cdecl creat(const char *_Filename,int _PermissionMode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_D
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:27:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:283:12: error: conflicting types for ‘chmod’
 extern int chmod (const char *__file, __mode_t __mode)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:25:0:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:311:15: note: previous declaration of ‘chmod’ was here
   int __cdecl chmod(const char *_Filename,int _AccessMode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRE
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:27:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:311:17: error: conflicting types for ‘umask’
 extern __mode_t umask (__mode_t __mask) __THROW;
                 ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:25:0:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:328:15: note: previous declaration of ‘umask’ was here
   int __cdecl umask(int _Mode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:27:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:320:12: error: conflicting types for ‘mkdir’
 extern int mkdir (const char *__path, __mode_t __mode)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:25:0:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:267:15: note: previous declaration of ‘mkdir’ was here
   int __cdecl mkdir (const char *) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:28:0:
/usr/include/fcntl.h:202:12: error: conflicting types for ‘creat’
 extern int creat (const char *__file, mode_t __mode) __nonnull ((1));
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_basics.h:23:0,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.h:23,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:22:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:314:15: note: previous declaration of ‘creat’ was here
   int __cdecl creat(const char *_Filename,int _PermissionMode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_D
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:29:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:283:12: error: conflicting types for ‘chmod’
 extern int chmod (const char *__file, __mode_t __mode)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_basics.h:23:0,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.h:23,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:22:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:311:15: note: previous declaration of ‘chmod’ was here
   int __cdecl chmod(const char *_Filename,int _AccessMode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRE
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:29:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:311:17: error: conflicting types for ‘umask’
 extern __mode_t umask (__mode_t __mask) __THROW;
                 ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_basics.h:23:0,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.h:23,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:22:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:328:15: note: previous declaration of ‘umask’ was here
   int __cdecl umask(int _Mode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:29:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:320:12: error: conflicting types for ‘mkdir’
 extern int mkdir (const char *__path, __mode_t __mode)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_basics.h:23:0,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.h:23,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:22:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:267:15: note: previous declaration of ‘mkdir’ was here
   int __cdecl mkdir (const char *) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
               ^
../src/bflib_fileio.c: In function ‘LbFileOpen’:
../src/bflib_fileio.c:237:43: error: ‘O_BINARY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         rc = _sopen(fname, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_BINARY, SH_DENYNO, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE
                                           ^
../src/bflib_fileio.c:237:43: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/intrin.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38,
                 from ../src/bflib_keybrd.c:25:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
../src/bflib_math.c: In function ‘LbRandomSeries’:
../src/bflib_math.c:746:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_lrotr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   *seed = _lrotr(i, 13);
           ^
../src/bflib_tcpsp.c:26:26: fatal error: SDL2/SDL_net.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL2/SDL_net.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/intrin.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38,
                 from ../src/bflib_video.c:27:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/intrin.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38,
                 from ../src/bflib_vidsurface.c:25:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
../src/config.c: In function ‘recognize_conf_command’:
../src/config.c:275:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strnicmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         if (strnicmp(buf+(*pos), commands[i].name, cmdname_len) == 0)
             ^
../src/config.c: In function ‘get_language_lwrstr’:
../src/config.c:424:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlwr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   strlwr(lang_str);
   ^
../src/front_network.c: In function ‘net_write_config_file’:
../src/front_network.c:503:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strupr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         strupr(net_config_info.str_atz);
         ^
../src/lvl_filesdk1.c: In function ‘get_level_number_from_file_name’:
../src/lvl_filesdk1.c:108:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strnicmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   if (strnicmp(fname,"map",3) != 0)
       ^
../src/lvl_script.c: In function ‘get_next_word’:
../src/lvl_script.c:446:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strupr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         strupr(param);
         ^
../src/lvl_script.c: In function ‘get_map_location_code_name’:
../src/lvl_script.c:792:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘itoa’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         itoa(apt->num, name, 10);
         ^
nicholas@LinuxNick ~/.apps/keeperfx/bin $ sudo i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 -I/usr/include -L/usr/local/lib -liconv ../src/*.c -o keeperfx/
[sudo] password for nicholas: 
../src/bflib_crash.c: In function ‘sigstr’:
../src/bflib_crash.c:77:10: error: ‘SIGBREAK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     case SIGBREAK : return "Ctrl-Break (Win32)";
          ^
../src/bflib_crash.c:77:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../src/bflib_crash.c: In function ‘LbErrorParachuteInstall’:
../src/bflib_crash.c:189:12: error: ‘SIGBREAK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     signal(SIGBREAK,ctrl_handler);
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:26:0:
/usr/include/fcntl.h:202:12: error: conflicting types for ‘creat’
 extern int creat (const char *__file, mode_t __mode) __nonnull ((1));
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:25:0:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:314:15: note: previous declaration of ‘creat’ was here
   int __cdecl creat(const char *_Filename,int _PermissionMode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_D
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:27:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:283:12: error: conflicting types for ‘chmod’
 extern int chmod (const char *__file, __mode_t __mode)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:25:0:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:311:15: note: previous declaration of ‘chmod’ was here
   int __cdecl chmod(const char *_Filename,int _AccessMode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRE
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:27:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:311:17: error: conflicting types for ‘umask’
 extern __mode_t umask (__mode_t __mask) __THROW;
                 ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:25:0:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:328:15: note: previous declaration of ‘umask’ was here
   int __cdecl umask(int _Mode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:27:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:320:12: error: conflicting types for ‘mkdir’
 extern int mkdir (const char *__path, __mode_t __mode)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_dernc.c:25:0:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:267:15: note: previous declaration of ‘mkdir’ was here
   int __cdecl mkdir (const char *) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:28:0:
/usr/include/fcntl.h:202:12: error: conflicting types for ‘creat’
 extern int creat (const char *__file, mode_t __mode) __nonnull ((1));
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_basics.h:23:0,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.h:23,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:22:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:314:15: note: previous declaration of ‘creat’ was here
   int __cdecl creat(const char *_Filename,int _PermissionMode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_D
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:29:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:283:12: error: conflicting types for ‘chmod’
 extern int chmod (const char *__file, __mode_t __mode)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_basics.h:23:0,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.h:23,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:22:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:311:15: note: previous declaration of ‘chmod’ was here
   int __cdecl chmod(const char *_Filename,int _AccessMode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRE
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:29:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:311:17: error: conflicting types for ‘umask’
 extern __mode_t umask (__mode_t __mask) __THROW;
                 ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_basics.h:23:0,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.h:23,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:22:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:328:15: note: previous declaration of ‘umask’ was here
   int __cdecl umask(int _Mode) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
               ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:29:0:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:320:12: error: conflicting types for ‘mkdir’
 extern int mkdir (const char *__path, __mode_t __mode)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bflib_basics.h:23:0,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.h:23,
                 from ../src/bflib_fileio.c:22:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/io.h:267:15: note: previous declaration of ‘mkdir’ was here
   int __cdecl mkdir (const char *) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
               ^
../src/bflib_fileio.c: In function ‘LbFileOpen’:
../src/bflib_fileio.c:237:43: error: ‘O_BINARY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         rc = _sopen(fname, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_BINARY, SH_DENYNO, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE
                                           ^
../src/bflib_fileio.c:237:43: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/intrin.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38,
                 from ../src/bflib_keybrd.c:25:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
../src/bflib_math.c: In function ‘LbRandomSeries’:
../src/bflib_math.c:746:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_lrotr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   *seed = _lrotr(i, 13);
           ^
../src/bflib_tcpsp.c:26:26: fatal error: SDL2/SDL_net.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL2/SDL_net.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/intrin.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38,
                 from ../src/bflib_video.c:27:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/intrin.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38,
                 from ../src/bflib_vidsurface.c:25:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:23: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
../src/config.c: In function ‘recognize_conf_command’:
../src/config.c:275:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strnicmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         if (strnicmp(buf+(*pos), commands[i].name, cmdname_len) == 0)
             ^
../src/config.c: In function ‘get_language_lwrstr’:
../src/config.c:424:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlwr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   strlwr(lang_str);
   ^
../src/front_network.c: In function ‘net_write_config_file’:
../src/front_network.c:503:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strupr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         strupr(net_config_info.str_atz);
         ^
../src/lvl_filesdk1.c: In function ‘get_level_number_from_file_name’:
../src/lvl_filesdk1.c:108:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strnicmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   if (strnicmp(fname,"map",3) != 0)
       ^
../src/lvl_script.c: In function ‘get_next_word’:
../src/lvl_script.c:446:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strupr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         strupr(param);
         ^
../src/lvl_script.c: In function ‘get_map_location_code_name’:
../src/lvl_script.c:792:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘itoa’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         itoa(apt->num, name, 10);
         ^
```

I am using the command `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 -I/usr/include -L/usr/local/lib -liconv ../src/*.c` for compiling. However, even adding an output location, doesn't spit out an output file.

I don't know what else to do here.

My system runs 64-bit Linux Mint version 18.1 on Cinnamon.

Comment: Is the question “Is it possible to cross-compile C++ source code, that was originally written for Microsoft's Windows to Gnu/linux?”

Comment: Most C++ for microsoft's Windows was written for Microsoft's C++ compiler. This is considered by many to be “C++, but not as we know it”, or in other words not standards compliment. Unless someone has put some effort in to making a Microsoft incompatible compiler, then you have no change.

Comment: But I thought the point of mingw was to bypass that and compile Windows source files from C and C++ on linux. Maybe I am misunderstanding?

Comment: The GNU / mingw toolchain may allow you to *cross*-compile (i.e. build software **on** Linux, but **for** Windows) - there's really no magic solution for turning Windows source code into a native Linux binary AFAIK - unless it happens to be "pure" C/C++ that doesn't rely on any Windows components. (It *may* be possible to cross-compile and then run it under Wine).

Comment: I want to avoid using wine. How can I tell if it happens to use pure C/C++? Is it possible keeperfx happens to be pure C/C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first set of errors happens because the source code is only intended for 32-bit targets. When building KeeperFX, you can force this (if your compiler is set up correctly) by running

```
make CPP="g++ -m32"
```

but then you run into missing headers — `windows.h`, `winbase.h`, `io.h`, `basetyps.h` when building `src/main.cpp` — which suggests that the code is written for Windows with no portability concerns. It’s not “pure C/C++”.

KeeperFX does appear to support building with some versions of MinGW or MinGW-w64 at least, but as has been pointed out in the comments that only allows you to build a Windows binary on Linux. So you can build on Linux, using

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=i686-w64-mingw32-
```

and an appropriate cross-compiler, but the resulting binary will need Wine to run on Linux. (On Mint, the appropriate cross-compiler is `g++-mingw-w64`.)

It *might* be possible to port KeeperFX to SDL without huge amounts of effort, I haven’t looked into it in detail.